# Página com mesmo slug de post_type wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Buenas

Tenho um post_type do wordpress que chama produtos.

Criei um archive-produtos.php e dentro dele tenho o loop. Dentro dela preciso ter, antes da lista um conteúdo editável, e pra isso tem a página chamada Produtos, dentro de Pages no wordpress.

Qual a melhor maneira de fazer isso sem que haja conflitos na url?

Att,

Comment: Adicione o código na pergunta.

Comment: Não entendi muito bem sua pergunta, você possui uma página já criada chamada Produtos ou um post_type chamado Produtos?

Comment: Os dois. Na verdade o post_type chama produtos. Tenho um archive-produtos.php e nele consigo fazer o loop normalmente. Porém, antes do loop preciso de um conteúdo dinâmico, que teria que estar dentro de páginas no menu wordpress. Se eu criar uma página produtos, pra wordpress pegar o global $post automaticamente, a url vai conflitar, a página com o post_type. Já criei uma página com url diferente do post_type e faço um loop pegando essa página dentro do archive-produtos. Desse jeito funciona, mas nem sei se é a melhor forma de fazer. :)

Answer (score 1):

Você tem que escolher qual página vai querer ficar com a URL seusite.com/produtos.

Se é a página que você está criando dentro do painel, você vai precisar mudar o permalink do post_type. Se você está registrando esse post_type programaticamente deve acrescentar o argumento rewrite, conforme [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#Arguments):

> rewrite
>       (boolean or array) (optional) Triggers the handling of rewrites for this post type. To prevent rewrites, set to false.
>       Default: true and use $post_type as slug
>       $args array
>       'slug' => string Customize the permalink structure slug. Defaults to the $post_type value. Should be translatable.
>       'with_front' => bool Should the permalink structure be prepended with the front base. (example: if your permalink structure is /blog/,
>   then your links will be: false->/news/, true->/blog/news/). Defaults
>   to true
>       'feeds' => bool Should a feed permalink structure be built for this post type. Defaults to has_archive value.
>       'pages' => bool Should the permalink structure provide for pagination. Defaults to true
>       'ep_mask' => const As of 3.4 Assign an endpoint mask for this post type. For more info see Rewrite API/add_rewrite_endpoint, Trac Ticket
>   19275, and this Make WordPress Plugins summary of endpoints.
>       If not specified and permalink_epmask is set, inherits from permalink_epmask
>       If not specified and permalink_epmask is not set, defaults to EP_PERMALINK

Aconselho também usar um arquivo diferente para essa página, ao invés de archive-produtos.php. O melhor é usar um template do tipo page-produtos.php e deixar o archive-produtos.php para um arquivo simples do post type produtos. Assim você não corre o risco de a página ser chamada pela url do post type e o conteúdo do primeiro loop não ser encontrado.

Se você quer que a página do custom post type produtos fique com essa url, aí é só mudar o título da página que você está criando dentro do Painel e lembrar de usar um template pra essa página. [Sobre templates](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates)

Comment: Muito Obrigado, galera. Realmente o jeito é fazer templates mesmo e/ou páginas e chamar o loop dentro do template. Archive, usar somente quando for simples e não necessitar que a página em si tenha um conteúdo dinâmico. Agradeço novamente a ideia de vocês.

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia, tive um problema semelhante uma vez. A página e o Custom Post Type possuíam o mesmo slug e para resolver passei a utilizar sempre nome singular para Custom Post Type, no seu caso seria produto ao invés de produtos.